How do I deal with "Internal C++ object (some object) already deleted"?
When I close a window which has a logger and then re-open the window, I get "RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide6.QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit) already deleted."(I made the logger based off of this post: Best way to display logs in pyqt?).
When I remove "self.deleteLater()" from LoggerWindow's closeEvent, I don't get the error since QWidget is not deleted. But the problem is that in my program, I need "self.deleteLater()" to detect that the window is closed (using self.(QWidget).destroyed.connect()).
Is there any way to avoid this error, or is there a different way to detect when a window closes?
This is my first time using logging, so I might be doing something wrong with it.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
import os
import logging
import sys


class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QPlainTextEdit(parent)
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)


class LoggerWindow(QWidget):
    parent_dir = os.getcwd()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.logger_text_edit = QTextEditLogger(self)
        self.logger_text_edit.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s]: %(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.logger_text_edit)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logging.info("Initialized")

        main_v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_v_layout.addWidget(self.logger_text_edit.widget)

        self.setLayout(main_v_layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.deleteLater()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        main_v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        button = QPushButton("Push!")
        main_v_layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(main_v_layout)

        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.logger_window = LoggerWindow()
        self.logger_window.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow(app)
window.show()

app.exec()



If you want to detect when a window is closed using signals, then create a custom signal and do not delete the window.

Thank you for the comment, I was able to solve the problem with that!

As suggested by the comment, creating a custom signal which emits when the window closes solved the problem. (How to create custom signal: PyQt5 - Detecting When Other Window Closes)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal
import os
import logging
import sys


class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QPlainTextEdit(parent)
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(msg)


class LoggerWindow(QWidget):
    signal = Signal()
    parent_dir = os.getcwd()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.logger_text_edit = QTextEditLogger(self)
        self.logger_text_edit.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s %(levelname)s]: %(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.logger_text_edit)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logging.info("Initialized")

        main_v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_v_layout.addWidget(self.logger_text_edit.widget)

        self.setLayout(main_v_layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.signal.emit()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()
        self.app = app
        main_v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("Push!")
        main_v_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(main_v_layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.logger_window = LoggerWindow()
        self.logger_window.show()
        self.logger_window.signal.connect(self.button.setText("Push Again"))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow(app)
window.show()

app.exec()

